# Deleting DataFrame row in a multilevel index Pandas based on column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following Multilevel DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ...:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
s
```

Lets say I would like to delete the whole row with index_0 bar and index_1 two

How may I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`drop` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
In [26]: s.drop(('bar','two'), axis=0)
Out[26]: 
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.450943 -1.615345 -0.862521  1.042495
baz one  1.200944  0.617102 -0.439342 -0.296142
    two -0.879343 -1.055805  0.682381  2.625398
foo one  0.191370 -0.212905 -0.415360 -1.437934
    two  0.458979  1.072584  0.485136  1.498859
qux one -2.137894 -0.872023 -0.382530 -0.550116
    two -1.490523 -2.999998  0.290653 -0.848422
```

The `axis=0` is not necessary (it's the default), but I include it just to be explicit that we are dropping rows, not columns.

---

If you had wanted to remove more than one row, say for example, both the 
`('bar','two')` and `('baz','one')` rows, then you could use `isin` to generate a boolean mask:

```
In [55]: s.index.isin((('bar','two'),('baz','one')))
Out[55]: array([False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and then use `s.loc` to select rows:

```
In [56]: s.loc[~s.index.isin((('bar','two'),('baz','one')))]
Out[56]: 
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.450943 -1.615345 -0.862521  1.042495
baz two -0.879343 -1.055805  0.682381  2.625398
foo one  0.191370 -0.212905 -0.415360 -1.437934
    two  0.458979  1.072584  0.485136  1.498859
qux one -2.137894 -0.872023 -0.382530 -0.550116
    two -1.490523 -2.999998  0.290653 -0.848422
```

The `~` inverts the mask so that we keep rows where the boolean mask is False.